# How to limit the memory usage of WinCE 6?

Tags: memory, windows-ce, boot

I have compiled a Wince 6 kernel using VS2005 platform builder. The target system have 256MB RAM, but I only want Wince 6 to use 128MB. How can I set this up? I am assuming to put maxmem=128MB in boot.ini, but I cannot find boot.ini in my wince 6 source code and any file inside platform builder directory.

Answer (score 2):

Update the RAM mapping in [config.bib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/ms904239.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think it a good thing to share too....
for example i fyou have a physical RAM 128MB. than your NK size is for example 30MB.
the total size reported you your system will be somehow less like 96MB because the NK are also occupied the RAM at the runtime.

/nansah

Comment: That's not always the case.  If your platform supports XIP, then the full 128 is going to be available to the OS.  Hardware mappings in config.bib can also have large impacts on reported available RAM.